# create project jar in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have a self-contained application in SBT. My data is stored on HDFS (the hadoop file system).How can I get a jar file to run my work on another machine.

The directory of my project is the following:

```
/MyProject
   /target
        /scala-2.11
                 /MyApp_2.11-1.0.jar
   /src
      /main
           /scala
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Java, in Scala, the file’s package name doesn’t have to match the directory name. In fact, for simple tests like this, 
you can place this file in the root directory of your SBT project, if you prefer.

From the root directory of the project, you can compile the project:

$ sbt compile
Run the project:

$ sbt run
Package the project:

$ sbt package

Here is link to understand:
http://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-to-compile-run-package-scala-project

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any dependencies then running `sbt package` will create a jar will all your code.

You can then run your Spark app as:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --name "an-app" my-app.jar
```

If your project has external dependencies (other than spark itself; if it's just Spark or any of it's dependencies, then the above approach still works), then you have two options:

1) Use the sbt [assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin to create an uper jar with your entire class-path. Running `sbt assembly` will create another jar which you can use in the same way as before.

2) If you only have very few simple dependecies (say just joda-time), then you can simply include them into your spark-submit script.

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --name "an-app" --packages "joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6" my-app.jar
```

Comment: I have two dependencies for spark-core and spark-mllib, I run by: spark-submit --class "an-app" --master local[4] target/scala-2.11/myproject_2.11-1.0.jar

Comment: I want to get my jar file or how to copy it in my local disc.

Comment: You just said where the jar is. Why are you having trouble copying it? I am confused ...